# PostgreSQL query to return the set of days between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I need to return the dates between the 05 of the last month and the 05 of the current month Example today is the 16/08/2022 I recuperate therefore the whole of the days between the 05/07/2022 and the 05/08/2022

For the moment I try with this query

```
SELECT DATE from Db_name where date between date_trunc('month', current_date-1) and date_trunc('month',current_date)
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com est pour les questions en anglais uniquement. Vous feriez mieux de traduire votre question, sinon elle sera bientôt fermée. (Vous pouvez utiliser translate.google.com pour traduire.)

Comment: This question is not written in English, and therefore does not meet the minimum requirements for Stack Overflow. All posts on this site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking if just want a sequence of dates then: `select generate_series('05/07/2022'::date, '05/08/2022'::date, '1 day');`. If you want to select dates in table that exist between the dates then `...between '05/07/2022'::date and '05/08/2022'::date`. If something else then you need to provide more information, in particular sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query is very much on track. Just a couple additional things about dates:

1. current_date-1 subtracts 1 day, you need to subtract 1 month. Thus current_date - interval '1 month'.
2. date_trunc(somedate) returns the 1st of the month so
   date_trunc('2022-08-17') returns 2022-08-01.
3. getting to the 5th of the month from the 1st just add `interval '4 days'`.
4. adding or subtracting intervals to dates results in timestamps.
   Since you want dates so needs to be cast back to date.

```
select * 
  from db_name 
 where some_date between (date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '1 month') + interval '4 days')::date
                     and (date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '4 days')::date;
```

But I will repeat **do not any reserved word or data type as a name**. At best is causes confusion, at worst it will run but do the wrong thing.